# Temperature Converter. How to accept a negative number as an input?

Tags: python, negative-number

I'm trying to create a python temp converter that will look at an input, see if it's in celsius or fahrenheit, then do a calculation.  My code attempts to verify that the input has both a number and a specific text string (separated by a space). I do the former by using a isnumeric operator. However, when negative number is input, it, as you know, sees the negative sign and does not verify that the string is numeric. Is the answer to strip the negative sign then add it back and declare it an integer?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide proper question

Comment: `str.isnumeric()` is not the correct way of checking whether a string can be converted to a valid Python int.

Comment: AMC thank you.  What do you suggest?

Comment: Can you publish the code that you've used so far?

Comment: Try passing the input string to `int()` or `float()` and if no exception is raised, then it's valid. (Use `try` and `except` to handle any exception that's raised.